# Custom Nested Wordpress Comments with avatar

Tags: functions, comments

I am developing a theme and has no idea how wordpress handles the comment outputs.

I have `wp_list_comments` in my comments.php, but I'm not sure how to customize the output to get the desired output as in the enclosed image.

Any suggestions on how to customize the output rendered by `wp_list_comments`?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plugin recommendations are off topic, so you will need to search this on your own. As for without a plugin, you can customize the the output of [`wp_list_comments`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments)

In `wp_list_comments`, there is a `callback` parameter which you can override with your own function.

This is the customized callback function that I currently use. It differs a bit from the desired output you are looking for. You must just swop the elements around to get them in the correct order you want. The styling will all be up to you as well.

Add this code in your functions.php

```
function pietergoosen_comments( $comment, $args, $depth ) {
    $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment;
    switch ( $comment->comment_type ) :
        case 'pingback' :
        case 'trackback' :
        if ( 'div' == $args['style'] ) {
            $tag = 'div';
            $add_below = 'comment';
        } else {
            $tag = 'li';
            $add_below = 'div-comment';
        }
    ?>
    <li <?php comment_class(); ?> id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>">
        <p><?php _e( 'Pingback:', 'pietergoosen' ); ?> <?php comment_author_link(); ?> <?php edit_comment_link( __( '(Edit)', 'pietergoosen' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?></p>
    <?php
            break;
        default :
        global $post;
    ?>
    <li <?php comment_class(); ?> id="li-comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>">
        <article id="div-comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>" class="comment-body">
                <footer class="comment-meta">
                    <div class="comment-author vcard">
                        <?php if ( 0 != $args['avatar_size'] ) echo get_avatar( $comment, $args['avatar_size'] ); ?>
                        <?php printf( __( '%s <span class="says">says:</span>' ), sprintf( '<b class="fn">%s</b>', get_comment_author_link() ) ); ?>
                    </div><!-- .comment-author -->

                    <div class="comment-metadata">
                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_comment_link( $comment->comment_ID ) ); ?>">
                            <time datetime="<?php comment_time( 'c' ); ?>">
                                <?php printf( _x( '%1$s at %2$s', '1: date, 2: time' ), get_comment_date(), get_comment_time() ); ?>
                            </time>
                        </a>
                        <?php edit_comment_link( __( 'Edit', 'pietergoosen' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
                    </div><!-- .comment-metadata -->

                    <?php if ( '0' == $comment->comment_approved ) : ?>
                    <p class="comment-awaiting-moderation"><?php _e( 'Your comment is awaiting moderation.', 'pietergoosen' ); ?></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </footer><!-- .comment-meta -->

                <div class="comment-content">
                    <?php comment_text(); ?>
                </div><!-- .comment-content -->

                <div class="reply">
                    <?php comment_reply_link( array_merge( $args, array( 'add_below' => 'div-comment', 'depth' => $depth, 'max_depth' => $args['max_depth'] ) ) ); ?>
                </div><!-- .reply -->
            </article><!-- .comment-body -->
    <?php
        break;
    endswitch; 
}
```

Now, in your comments.php template, look for your `wp_list_comments()` function. Replace that with the following code

```
<ol class="commentlist">
    <?php wp_list_comments( array(
    'callback' => 'pietergoosen_comments',
    'style'      => 'ol',
    'short_ping' => true,
    'avatar_size'=> 34,
    ) );
   ?>
</ol><!-- .commentlist -->
```

This should get you started